# Gap increased between elements

Tags: html, css

I am creating a registration form, but suddenly a gap increased between an elements.
Here is the link of my code.
http://jsbin.com/mujixepete/2/
See gender and date of birth to get the idea of what i am talking about.
Can anybody help me out to fix this error?

Comment: The number of `<td>`s are different under the `<tr>`s, use  colspan` to fix that first.

Comment: Please always put the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh. This kind of layouts are really out-dated, and not recommended at all. The reason of the "gaps" the layout itself. Because you placed 280px wide elements in the table column, it will be 280px wide at least, everywhere above and under.

Now, you can change the structure to something modern, or if you dont want the trouble, just put the stuff in the 2nd column: [like this](http://jsbin.com/damobenoyu/1/edit).

I suggest the first option after all.

Comment: Okay thanks, i am going to change my structure to table less to look for modern.

Answer (score 0):

For each tr in your table, you must have the same number of tds. If you have a different number of tds you need to use the colspan attribute to fix it. For instance:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Col 1</td>
        <td colspan="2">Col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Col 1</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
        <td>Col 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The second column in the first row will stretch to be the same size as columns 2 and 3 in the second row.

This will work although generally using tables for layout is unpopular nowadays (layout is done using CSS instead).